# How can the navbar be edited such that the link 1 appears aligned to the right side link 2 at the center and link 3 on the right

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I have tried using flex property and justify content but that doesn't work as well. I tried the below mentioned code.

the aim is to make a website with a logo on top and navbar right below like shown below

[how the site looks like as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zk8q.png)

```
    <header class="top-part">
       <div class="logo"> 
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" height=100px width="237px"   >
       </div>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ">
            <li >
              <a class="nav-link" id="home"href="#">link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="cart" href="#">link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="contact"href="#">link 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
</head>




css :
    @media screen and (min-width:777px){
    .nav-link {
      padding:18px 0;
      min-width:120px;
    }
    .navbar {
      padding: 0
    }
  }

.header{
    position:sticky ;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing some research and practicing with some basic HTML/CSS, so you understand the basics and know what everything does.

For this specific example you should look into 'flexbox'!

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605666807892-8c11d020bede?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fGJhbmFuYXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    <nav class="w-100 d-flex bg-light">
      <a class="p-2 bd-highlight text-black-50 text-decoration-none" href="">link 1</a>
      <a class="p-2 bd-highlight text-black-50 text-decoration-none" href="">link 2</a>
      <a class="p-2 bd-highlight text-black-50 text-decoration-none" href="">link 3</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
a:first-of-type{
  float: left;
}
a:last-of-type{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img style="width: 100px;" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605666807892-8c11d020bede?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fGJhbmFuYXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
  <nav>
    <a href="">link 1</a>
    <a href="">link 2</a>
    <a href="">link 3</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

Add `d-flex`, `flex-row`, and `justify-content-center` to your parent div containing the logo.

You can add the same to your parent div for the links (ul and li's)

Your links are left aligned, so you can add "text-center" to classes of your `<ul>` element.

It would look like this:

```html
<header class="top-part">
       <div class="logo d-flex flex-row justify-content-center"> 
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" height=100px width="237px"   >
       </div>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  d-flex flex-row justify-content-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" id="home" href="#">link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="cart" href="#">link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="contact"href="#">link 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Also just a note, I see your code above is ending with `</head>`. Make sure you are not putting this code in the `<head>` of your site, but the `<body>` :)